# Flutter: How to show loading screen after the url is added?

Tags: android, flutter, url

I'm building a URL shortner app. I want to show a loading screen after the url is entered. This is my code. I'm a beginner to flutter. Please help me since this is my first app. The code is given below. As you can see the I'm using FutureBuilder so if the url list is empty it shows a corresponding message but I want it to disappear after the ok button of the alertdialog is pressed.

```
class _homePageState extends State<homePage> {
  List userURL = List();
  List item = List();

  Future<List> getdata() async {
    //JSON Parser
    var url = 'https://api.shrtco.de/v2/shorten?url=${userURL.last}';
    var respons = await http.get(url);
    var result = jsonDecode(respons.body);
    item.add(result['result']['short_link']); //dictionary parse

    print(item);
    return item;
  }

  createAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
    //method for alertdialog
    //promise to return string
    TextEditingController customController =
        TextEditingController(); //new texteditingc object
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Enter URL: "),
            content: TextField(
              controller: customController,
            ),
            actions: [
              MaterialButton(
                elevation: 5.0,
                child: Text("OK"),
                onPressed: () {
                  if (customController.text != null &&
                      customController.text != "") {
                    userURL.add(customController.text);
                  }

                  setState(() {});
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              )
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String temp;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Shortie"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: getdata(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.data == null) {
                return Center(
                    child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.sentiment_very_dissatisfied,
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        size: 80,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "No short links to display",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey[700],
                          fontSize: 15,
                          //fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]));
              } else {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      leading: Icon(Icons.link),
                      title: Text(snapshot.data[index]),
                      subtitle: Text(userURL[index]),
                      onTap: () {
                        Share.share(
                            'Check out the short link I just shared with the application Shortie: ${snapshot.data[index]}',
                            subject: 'Shortie short link');
                        print(snapshot.data[index]);
                      },
                    );
                  },
                );
              }
            },
          )),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          createAlertDialog(context).then((onValue) {
            temp = onValue;
            print(temp);
          });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the [connection state class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ConnectionState-class.html) of the FutureBuilder as follows:

```
FutureBuilder(
      future: getdata(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                 return CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.blue);
              } else {
                 return Container();
              }
       },
);
```

Also, on your button you need to call `setState()` to trigger the view reload, which in turn will again check the connectionState, if the `async` function is still in progress you will see the loading indicator, otherwise something you put in else